# DISTINCT TOP with ORDER BY in MS Access returns duplicates

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, duplicates, sql-order-by, distinct

The following query seems to ignore DISTINCT in Microsoft Access. I expect 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, but it returns 1980, 1981, 1981, 1981, ..., 1982, 1982, 1983:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 DatePart('yyyy', HIREDATE) FROM emp ORDER BY 1
```

A very similar query for SQL Server works perfectly well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 DatePart(YEAR, HIREDATE) FROM emp ORDER BY 1
```

Back to Access, it works without the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 DatePart('yyyy', HIREDATE) FROM emp
```

But other queries like the following work well with ORDER BY, and remove duplicates as well, as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 JOB FROM emp ORDER BY 1
```

Could someone properly explain why first query fails and the others don't.

Comment: Maybe Colin's answer in this post will help you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135347/sql-statement-returns-wrong-values-top-n-order-by) Bye!

Comment: Partially. But I suspect it's more than TOP being executed before ORDER BY. Why my 4th query returns a proper result, for instance?

Comment: Firstly, ensure you have the correct "Data Type" defined for the HIREDATE column. The correct data type to store Date and/and Time is "Date/Time".

I hope the following Sql should solve the problem?

`SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 DatePart('yyyy',HIREDATE)
FROM emp
ORDER BY DatePart('yyyy',HIREDATE)  ASC`

Comment: It was datetime and ORDER BY 1 is not a problem. And your query obviously returns the same wrong results.

Comment: The  `top` directive doesn't return the top `n` items. Instead it returns at least `n` distinct items determined by the ordering of the result. The top directive in T-SQL (SQL Server) however never returns more than n items. You can specify the clauses `with ties` and `order by` along with `top`, one can observe the same behavior as in Access.